# Want help in display toast on click button which is of double type

Tags: android

I want to display the total calculated with the help of toast msg when the button is clicked but everytime I click on it I get 0.0 can anyone help me fix this?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String s, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6;
        String result;
        final String disp;
        int a, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6;
        double total = 0;
        double price;

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        CheckBox opt = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opt);
        CheckBox opt1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opt1);
        CheckBox opt2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opt2);
        CheckBox opt3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opt3);
        CheckBox opt4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opt4);
        CheckBox opt5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opt5);
        CheckBox opt6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opt6);

        EditText oid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oid);
        EditText oid1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oid1);
        EditText oid2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oid2);
        EditText oid3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oid3);
        EditText oid4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oid4);
        EditText oid5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oid5);
        EditText oid6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oid6);


        if (opt.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s = opt.getText().toString();
            a = Integer.parseInt(oid1.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a);
        }
        if (opt1.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s1 = opt1.getText().toString();
            a1 = Integer.parseInt(oid2.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a1);
        }
        if (opt2.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s2 = opt2.getText().toString();
            a2 = Integer.parseInt(oid3.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a2);
        }
        if (opt3.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s3 = opt3.getText().toString();
            a3 = Integer.parseInt(oid4.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a3);
        }
        if (opt4.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s4 = opt4.getText().toString();
            a4 = Integer.parseInt(oid5.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a4);
        }
        if (opt5.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s5 = opt5.getText().toString();
            a5 = Integer.parseInt(oid5.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a5);
        }
        if (opt6.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s6 = opt6.getText().toString();
            a6 = Integer.parseInt(oid6.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a6);
        }

        result = String.valueOf(total);
        disp=result;

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toastMsg(disp);
            }
        });
    }
        public void toastMsg(String result) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();

        }
    }
```

I tried to remove the final keyword because maybe that was preventing me from updating the values to the string but no success.
I am just confused how to proceed.

Comment: run your calculations on button click and then display result

Answer (score 0):

Print result variable in log cat and see it contain any value or not... i think your result variable not contain any value. you can show toast without converting double into string ..
as

```
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, total+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
```

try to do that.. paste your calculation code into button click

```
 if (opt.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s = opt.getText().toString();
            a = Integer.parseInt(oid1.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a);
        }
        if (opt1.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s1 = opt1.getText().toString();
            a1 = Integer.parseInt(oid2.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a1);
        }
        if (opt2.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s2 = opt2.getText().toString();
            a2 = Integer.parseInt(oid3.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a2);
        }
        if (opt3.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s3 = opt3.getText().toString();
            a3 = Integer.parseInt(oid4.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a3);
        }
        if (opt4.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s4 = opt4.getText().toString();
            a4 = Integer.parseInt(oid5.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a4);
        }
        if (opt5.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s5 = opt5.getText().toString();
            a5 = Integer.parseInt(oid5.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a5);
        }
        if (opt6.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s6 = opt6.getText().toString();
            a6 = Integer.parseInt(oid6.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a6);
        }

        result = String.valueOf(total);
        disp=result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void calcResult()
   {
        String disp;
        if (opt.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s = opt.getText().toString();
            a = Integer.parseInt(oid1.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a);
        }
        if (opt1.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s1 = opt1.getText().toString();
            a1 = Integer.parseInt(oid2.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a1);
        }
        if (opt2.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s2 = opt2.getText().toString();
            a2 = Integer.parseInt(oid3.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a2);
        }
        if (opt3.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s3 = opt3.getText().toString();
            a3 = Integer.parseInt(oid4.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a3);
        }
        if (opt4.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s4 = opt4.getText().toString();
            a4 = Integer.parseInt(oid5.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a4);
        }
        if (opt5.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s5 = opt5.getText().toString();
            a5 = Integer.parseInt(oid5.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a5);
        }
        if (opt6.isChecked()) {
            price = 13.0;
            s6 = opt6.getText().toString();
            a6 = Integer.parseInt(oid6.getText().toString());
            total += (price * a6);
        }

        result = String.valueOf(total);
        disp=result;
        toastMsg(disp);

}
```

create a method as written in my answer,which contains code for calculation,then call that method in the button click event like below,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                calcResult()
            }
        });
```

and dont make that disp final make it calcResult methods local variable.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Getting this error message now and app crashes :(

Comment: Solved it.
There was a minor id mistake so was not able to retrive data

Thank you so much for the help.